# How to convert from from multiple-dimension array to one-dimension array?

Tags: php

I have the following array returned by my script.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 67
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 68
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 69
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 70
        )

)
```

How can I convert it to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 67

    [1] => 68

    [2] => 69

    [3] => 70
)
```

I'm only interested in the IDs returned.

Answer (score 3):

[`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is one possibility since it accumulates any value returned by the callback into its returned array. The callback then just needs to return the `id` :

```
$flat = array_map(function($a) {return $a['id'];}, $orig_array);
```

The above requires PHP 5.3+, since it uses an anonymous function, but the same can be achieved with a named function passed as a string to `array_map()`.

Otherwise, a `foreach` loop is pretty conventional and can preserve the original keys had then been non-sequential.

```
$flat = array();
foreach ($orig_array as $key => $a) {
  $flat[$key] = $a['id'];
}
```

Comment: @chris [there is no built-in `array_pluck()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) tmk.  Lots of examples on how to make them though.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this function, but try this suggestion: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php#104184

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $arr);
$final = $temp['id'];
print_r($final);
```

Why that works is tricky. Honestly, just use a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing [@Mickael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874403/1249581), you can also use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function:

```
function format(&$item, $key) {
    $item = $item["id"];
}

array_walk($arr, "format");
```

Or in one line with lambda function:

```
array_walk($arr, create_function('&$item, $key', '$item = $item["id"];'));
```

It works with your array directly, hence we can easily call it "array converting".